# How to put local node package on path?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Newbie question. I have chosen not to install express with -g option. I did not use npm -g which would put it on the path globally. Instead it is installed in my local mac user directory. What I am not clear on is exactly what or how you put a package like express on the path so it can be invoked etc?  What exactly needs to be on the path (node_modules?) so these packages are available just like a -g installation? I could have used home-brew I suppose but anyway, I now have all node packages and everything local.  Another situation is that I am not able to run any of the nodejs tutorials.  Although there might be smarter ways to do this, I wonder if sudo is really such a good way to install a development package ....

Now for example, I want to run the tutorial javascripting which is a nodejs tutorial.  How do I do this.  If I just type:
Mac1$  javascripting

it finds nothing.

Same for
Mac1$ express

UPDATE:  THIS WAS ANSWERED IN THE COMMENTS

The commands exist in a hidden directory after a regular

```
    install npm install express
```

in my case this the command goes here:  /users/MAC1/node_modules/.bin

It is this path that needs to be placed on the $PATH as described in the first comment.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Here is an article which describes in good detail how to add a program to the PATH: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/ As you did not give use any further information this is as much as can be done.  The article describes setting the PATH for a single user or for all accounts.

Comment: On Windows, commands and binaries are found in `node_modules/.bin`. I imagine it's the same on OSX, but if not, you need to add the directory containing the script files and binaries, wherever those are. Since it's in your user directory, you would probably do well to have one of the scripts that gets executed when you start the shell (`.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` for examples in `bash`) add the path to the environment variable.

Comment: `sudo` is often required to install much of anything on *nix systems (which Mac OSX is one).

Comment: well let me clarify. What would I need to add to $PATH so that a newly installed package like one of the demo's would be visible?

Answer (score 1):

npm installes executable to two places. By default running a `npm install` in a project will install any binaries in `./node_modules/.bin`. When you use the `-g` flag (`npm install -g package-name`) it will install into a global path. You can find out the global path by running `npm bin -g`. Add that to your path and globally installed executables will be accessible.

You can also add `./node_modules/.bin` to your path to allow easy access to executables added by packages in your project folder. I admit to using this on a **trusted** local machine. However, this is very dangerous and **not a recommended** way to expose the executables in the `node_modules` directory.

Best alternative is to add the executable to the [scripts section](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts) of the `package.json` file and then use `npm run-script <command>` which will auto prepend the `./node_modules/.bin` when executing.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "foo --arguments"
  }
}
```

Example

```
$ npm install foo
$ ls ./node_modules/.bin
foo
$ npm run-script foo
# Executes:
./node_modules/.bin/foo --arguments
```